# Laravel 4 total in table footer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I don't know if I'm not holding my toungue right or something, but I'm trying to get a total in the table footer.  I have no doubt there is something I'm missing, here is what I tried:

```
$labors = Labor::where('created_at', '>=', new DateTime('today'))->get()->sum('labor');
```

Which works well up until here:

```
->sum('labor')
```

Then I get:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::sum()
```

So I'm obviously using it incorrectly because it's in the docs here:

http://four.laravel.com/docs/queries

Some feedback would be much appreciated. :)

I think this might actually be relevant:

```
public function index()
{
    $labors = Labor::where('created_at', '>=', new DateTime('today'))->sum('labor');

    return View::make('labors.index', compact('labors'));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

```
$labors = Labor::where('created_at', '>=', new DateTime('today'))->get();
```

The above gets the array for use in the foreach.

```
$laborTotal = Labor::where('created_at', '>=', new DateTime('today'))->sum('labor');
```

That gets the total. So then is all you need to do is sent them both to the view and just use the total in the footer of the table:

```
return View::make('labors.index', compact('labors', 'laborTotal'));
```

View something like:

```
@foreach ($labors as $labor)
<tr> ... </tr>
@endforeach
<tr><td>{{ $laborTotal }}</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do a foreach, you will have to do 2 queries:

```
$total = Labor::where('created_at', '>=', new DateTime('today'))->sum('labor');

$labors = Labor::where('created_at', '>=', new DateTime('today'))->get();
```

This is because sum() returns an integer with the sum, not a collection.

Comment: Sorry now I'm getting Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), so can you not compact and send it to the view?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it should be

```
$labors = Labor::where('created_at', '>=', new DateTime('today'))->sum('labor');
```

This is as per [Eloquent Aggregates](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent) you were looking at the Fluent docs

You don't need to `compact` $labors now though as it's a string not an array

Comment: So if its not an array i'm assuming it doesn't send back all the fields just a total?